# How can I use Gmaps Library in Python

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

My goal is to use the gmaps library and make the image appear, but the image does not appear.

```py
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

gmaps.configure(api_key="AIzaSyCtd6p2bI-ZTdHvBlEXhhpO8xi5uHfiedk")
earthquake_df=gmaps.datasets.load_dataset_as_df("earthquakes")
print(earthquake_df.head())

locations = earthquake_df[['latitude', 'longitude']]
weights = earthquake_df['magnitude']
print(locations)
print(weights)

fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations=locations, weights=weights))
fig
```

This is the code, but Jupyter does not display images in Notebook and gives an error message.

```
[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Model class 'FigureModel' from module 'jupyter-gmaps' is loaded but can not be instantiated
TypeError: Class constructor L cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new t (http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/jupyter-gmaps/index.js?v=20231220195354:39:179771)
    at u._make_model (http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/jupyter-js-widgets/extension.js?v=20231220195354:2:747368)
```

Comment: Your title is inconsistent with your issue. You seem to be using gmaps in Python, instead you'd get errors with a stacktrace when you try to run that code block you share. I think you meant to post a title like 'How can I view a Gmaps figure in Jupyter'? Did you try the steps instructed to fix, or at least bypass, [this issue entitled 'jupyter-gmaps loaded but cannot be instantiated' here](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/issues/359#issuecomment-1272628114), which looks just like your issue? (Hopefully you didn't actually share your real API key here.) Anyway, if your issue is like that ...

Comment: <continued> one you'd need to provide more information to get much help. The versions back then really mattered and you don't include any of that information.

Comment: Oh wait! I fear you are trying to use abandonware. Is this the software you are trying to use [here](https://pypi.org/project/gmaps/)? That hasn't been updated since 2019 (, and confusingly here [here](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/releases) makes it seem like that may have been longer??). Jupyter has evolved a lot in the last four years. What versions of Jupyter are involved on your end? **Or** have you considered using something actively being developed? What is your goal here?

Comment: As mentioned by Wayne above, as a new user in Stack Overflow, we highly suggest that you go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your chances of getting help.